# String won't print with cout

Tags: c++, string

What I am trying to do is copy two strings to a third one leaving as many spaces in the third one as the sum of the characters of the first two strings without using `strcpy` or anything similar, the code below won't print the `stc` string. It runs but it wont print it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int i, j = 0, k = 0, str_1 = 0, str_2 = 0, str_3 = 0, space = 0;
  char sta[40];
  char stb[40];
  char stc[100] = { };

  cout << "Enter sentence: " << endl << endl;
  cin.getline(sta, 39);
  cout << "Enter Second Sentence: " << endl << endl;
  cin.getline(stb, 39);

  for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    if (sta[i] == '\0') {
      break;
    } else {
      str_1++;
    }
  }
  cout << "The first sentence has: " << str_1 << " characters" << endl << endl;

  for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    if (stb[i] == '\0') {
      break;
    } else {
      str_2++;
    }
  }
  cout << "The second sentence has: " << str_2 << " characters" << endl << endl;

  space = str_1 + str_2;
  for (i = 0; sta[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    stc[space] = sta[i];
    space++;
    str_3++;
  }
  for (j = 0; stb[j] != '\0'; j++) {
    stc[space] = stb[j];
    space++;
    str_3++;
  }
  stc[space] = '\0';
  cout << "The third sentence is: " << stc << endl << endl;
  cout << "And has " << str_3 << " characters " << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Some formatting would be nice. Also what do you mean it doesn't print? Do you get an error or something?

Comment: no it works but it wont print the string named stc it leaves a blank space

Comment: I would suggest that you use a debugging tool to step through the code up to the point where it prints the string and make sure the string is what you would expect it to be

Comment: Well i tried your code and the output look all ok except for the stc array that he was not empty at the beginning so some strange characters appear.

Comment: it prints everything else except the stc string.

Comment: oh my bad i misread the question. your problem is that in the stc array, there are '\0' character at the beginning so when it start to read it, it already think it is the end of the string

Comment: how is that possible, i left out the '\0' from both strings?

Comment: Look at your algorithm. Where you you think you're putting *anything* into `stc[]` *before* the index position of `str_1 + str_2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're attempting to initialize `stc`, but this:

```
char stc[100] = { };
```

Is not doing what you think it's doing. In fact, it should be initializing the array with all zero values, which is the same as the NUL terminator `'\0'` character, which causes printing of the array later to stop on the first character. Unfortunately, I don't think the standard allows you to default initialize the elements with anything other than 0, so saying `char stc[100] = {' '}` is out.

You could instead add spaces as you test characters in `sta` and `stb`:

```
char stc[100];
// ...
for (i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
    if (sta[i] == '\0')
      break;
    else {
      str_1++;
      stc[space++] = ' ';
    }
  }
// and the same for stb. Now you don't need to assign space = str_1 + str_2
```

### [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0a498545d97b4211)

---

Of course this could all be easier if you were to use `std::string` and algorithms from std::algorithm, but it appears you want to do things the hard way. Maybe start by writing a helper function for counting characters?

Comment: solved but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that in the stc array, there are '\0' character at the beginning so when it start to read it, it already think it is the end of the string .
Instead of doing :

`space = str_1 + str_2;`

just do

`space = 0;`

And dont forget to initialise the string like this

```
char stc[100] = "";
```

If you dont there will be strange character already in it and you wont know when the string end

In this way the array will start to be fill from the beginning and not from a random place.

Comment: Beat me to it by one minute, nice work

Comment: i don't want it to fill from from tyhe beginning i want to start filling from the sum of the characters of both strings

Comment: Why would you want this? It doesnt make sense to start in the middle of a char array

Comment: @KarloShehaj Your question is *screaming* for a input/output sample data set. Put it in your question.

Comment: @KarloShehaj Then at the very least you need to set all of the spaces you skipped to an empty string because right now you aren't initializing the first characters in `stc`, so who knows what could be in those spots

Comment: i know i am just trying to see if it works and exercising.

Comment: It would work but you cannot predicted what will be before the string. So as soon as you will print it , you will see some strange characters and who know if there was not the character '\0' in it? This mean the end of the string so you could also never see your string because the programm will think your string is already ended.

Comment: how can i avoid that?

Comment: Like i said, you have to start filling your char array for the index 0 the beginning, from this you are sure to know all the character you put in it. If you really want some blank space before, you will have to put the character ' ' in it the amount of time you want.